# What do you think about my Django model structure?

Tags: django

1. My project has 2 or more different kind of models as post
2. And i want to bookmark for all kind of post models
3. I need dashboard or timeline that shows bookmarked posts whatever the kind of that post

So i thought 2 plans.

**First Plan :**

Making different bookmark model at every post

Like :

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = AutoOneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)#its_from_django-annoying

class Post1(models.Model):
    text1 = models.TextField(max_length=110)

class Post2(models.Model):
    text2 = models.TextField(max_length=120)

class bookmarkForPost1(models.Model):
    who_user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    what_bookmarked = models.ForeignKey(Post1)

class bookmarkForPost2(models.Model):
    who_user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    what_bookmarked = models.ForeignKey(Post2)
```

And do something for dashboard in views.py

**Second Plan :**

Making PostProfile model and bookmark it

Like :

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = AutoOneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)

class PostProfile(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    #Do something to connect Post1 or Post2

class Post1(models.Model):
    text1 = models.TextField(max_length=110)
    #Do something to connect PostProfile

class Post2(models.Model):
    text2 = models.TextField(max_length=120)
    #Do something to connect PostProfile

class bookmarkForPosts(models.Model):
    who_user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    what_bookmarked = models.ForeignKey(PostProfile)
```

Second Plan is seemed to be simple and good for my eyes.

Second Plan, i can't sure where i put OneToOneField. In PostProfile or In Post1(+Post2)? Plus, I can't understand how to auto-create PostProfile just after creating of Post1 or Post2. 
But Second Plan is good at that there are no needs to do something in views.py

**What i ask is that :**

1. Is there are serious performance difference between First Plan and Second Plan? If it is, What is better?
2. Would you give me some advice to complete Second Plan?

Comment: You might consider migrating your question to code review if it's about gathering comments on ideas and styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this: define a type of post so you can have many more types of post in the future, and a `UserBookmark` so a user can have as many bookmarks he wants:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # its a good practice from django
    user = OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    P_TYPE_1 = 1
    P_TYPE_2 = 2
    TAB_P_TYPE = {
        P_TYPE_1: _("Type 1"),
        P_TYPE_2: _("Type 2"),
    }
    post_type = models.IntegerField(
        choices=[(a, b) for a, b in list(TAB_P_TYPE.items())],
        default=P_TYPE_1)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=110)

class UserPostBookmark(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer